# String to date time format in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, datetime

I have a csv file that contains the date column. The dates are in the format "1stNov", "22ndNov" etc. How do I programatically convert these to date time in Pandas?

Comment: Please show your data

Comment: So the last three letters are months?

Comment: try: `pd.read_csv(filepath, parse_dates = True)`

Comment: Yes the last three are months

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *not* a Pandas-specific problem but a problem in string/pattern matching. Use [Python's `strftime` directives](http://strftime.org/). Note also you *must* provide a year: `datetime` objects internally must hold a year. So with regular Python:

```
from datetime import datetime

L = ["1stNov", "22ndNov"]
res = [datetime.strptime(i[:-5] + i[-3:] + '2018', '%d%b%Y') for i in L]

[datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 22, 0, 0)]
```

Or with Pandas:

```
s = pd.Series(L)
res = pd.to_datetime(s.str[:-5] + s.str[-3:] + '2018', format='%d%b%Y')

0   2018-11-01
1   2018-11-22
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension with `parser`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':["1stNov", "22ndNov"]})

from dateutil import parser
df['dates'] = [parser.parse(f'{x[:-3]} {x[-3:]} 2018') for x in df['dates']]
```

Or remove `st`, `nd` strings and convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
#python 3.6+ solution with f-strings
dates = [(f'{x[:-5]}{x[-3:]}2018') for x in df['dates']]
#python bellow 3.6
#dates = ['{}{}2018'.format(x[:-5], x[-3:]) for x in df['dates']]
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%d%b%Y')

print (df)
       dates
0 2018-11-01
1 2018-11-22
```